# Neo4j Creating relationships between all nodes in a list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm creating relationships where people are mentioned in articles. Each article has its own title and has a comma-separated list of people that are mentioned within it in a single field in the original CSV.

```
MERGE (article:Article{
  title:row.Title
})

FOREACH (name IN split(row.People, ",") |
  MERGE (person:Person {title:trim(name)})
  MERGE (person)-[:MENTIONED_IN]->(article))

;
```

I now want to create a relationship of [:MENTIONED_WITH] between all the people that are mentioned in each article, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want obtain something like that?

```
WITH "sylvain, nicolas, christophe" AS people 
MERGE (article:ArticleTest{
  title:"MyTitle"
})

FOREACH (name IN split(people, ",") |
  MERGE (person:Person {title:trim(name)})
  MERGE (person)-[:MENTIONED_IN]->(article))
WITH article
MATCH (p:Person)-[:MENTIONED_IN]->(article)
MATCH (p2:Person)-[:MENTIONED_IN]->(article) WHERE p2.title<>p.title
MERGE (p)-[:MENTIONED_WITH]-(p2)
```